# Run Alphanet and Mainnet on the same VPS

Tags: node, setup, tezos-client

How might I go about running alphanet and mainnet on the same server, without docker images? Here is my current setup:

~/alphanet/tezos-node is where I have the tezos binaries for what I intend to be the alphanet instance. I execute this using pm2 process manager with tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8373

~/mainnet/tezos-node is where I have the tezos binaries for what I intend to be the mainnet instance. I execute this using pm2 process manager with tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8372

I also have nginx configured to serve proxypasses via https mapping alphanet and mainnet independently, so my applications can access the RCP methods via https.

Sidenote: I am also interested in securing my internet-facing nodes with a secure token. Would I have to implement a custom solution for this, or is there a config option or something similar to handle this within the node itself?

Edit: I have alphanet running fine, but when I try to fireup my mainnet instance, it fails because the chain data directory (~/.tezos-node) is locked to alphanet. So I am guessing I just need a config option to tell my mainnet instance to use a different data directory and identity.

Edit2 startup scripts:

alphanet:

/home/xyz/alphanet/tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8733 --data-dir /home/xyz/.tezos-node-alphanet

mainnet:

/home/xyz/mainnet/tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --data-dir /home/xyz/.tezos-node-mainnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a different data-dir, RPC port, **and** P2P port, like:
`--net-addr :10001 --rpc-addr :10002 --data-dir /some/path`

The `tezos-node` executables should be compiled from each respective branch `mainnet` / `alphamet` too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this now  "Error:
              An other tezos node is probably running on one of these
            addresses (127.0.0.1:8372). Please choose another RPC port." 

I've edited my question with my startup scripts

Comment: Your edit2 does not contain the `--net-addr ..` option. The 4 ports should be different.